# Blazor Server: Convert blob locally stored in browser to Base64 String

Tags: javascript, jquery, blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

I am creating an application in Blazor Server Net 6

I was able to save the image as a blob on the local browser by going through the documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/images?view=aspnetcore-7.0#stream-image-data

The images are rendering perfectly in the browser
[image: Image being rendered after being converted into a blob]

The Blob URL looks something like this

blob:https://localhost:7066/94065f17-5b19-47e4-9256-59f3e237a662

Now, I need to read the blob as a base 64 string. I tried to use IHTTPClient as mentioned below

```
var result=await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(_card.LogoImageDetails.ActualImage);
```

But, it throws an exception given below
[image]

Waiting for an efficient solution to solve this issue

Regards

Saad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

Created JS methods like this:

```
const blobToBase64 = async blob => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result)
        reader.error = (err) => reject(err)
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
    })
}

window.convertBlobURLToBase64 = async (url) => {
    const response = await fetch(url)
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const imageBase64 = await blobToBase64(blob)
    return imageBase64; 
}
```

Use JSInterop to get the base 64 string

```
 private async Task UploadImagesOnBlobAsync()
    {
        var result=await _jsRunTime.InvokeAsync<string>("convertBlobURLToBase64", _card.LogoImageDetails.ActualImage);
    }
```